# Rails_admin, Assigning Devise's current_user to model inside action

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, devise, rails-admin

I have Devise Model `Person` which will log in and manage `rails_admin` app.

I have model called `Model` which has `updater` that was added by `mongoid-history`.

In order to set who updated my story I need to do something like this:

```
model = Model.new
model.updater = Person.first
model.save
```

According to this [link to github](https://github.com/aq1018/mongoid-history/issues/139), I can not set `current_person`, which created by Devise automatically. That's means that I need to set `updater` manually each time when something happens to my `Model`.

How to get `current_person` and set it to `Model` where `rails_admin's` action happens?

I only know that I need to write something to each action in `initializers/rails_admin.rb`

Comment: [This](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15680541/accessing-devise-current-user-within-model) might help. Ajay's answer. I did something like this before.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have found one solution for my question, but I don't know if it is good aproach or not.

If I want to assign my `current_person` in `edit` action I needed to write this:

```
config.model Model do

   edit do
     field :updater_id, :hidden do
     visible true
     def value
       bindings[:view]._current_user.id
     end
    end
   end

end
```

It createds hidden field which has asigned ID of current person which is logged in.

Comment: This creates a hidden field that can be manipulated by the user or in the POST data, which makes this solution not secure.

Answer (score 0):

There's no access to `current_user` from the Model, because ActiveRecord models can be used independently from Rails apps, they can be used without logging in.

It is the controller that (often) requires the user to login and so has access to the user session and the `current_user` method. The controller must therefore do the work of setting the updater on the Model.

Perhaps you could set a callback method in the controller that acts on any action that modifies the model and sets the updater there.

Answer (score 0):

[Mr.D's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/32201822/1042470) seems not to work (at least as of rails_admin 2.0.2); bindings doesn't have a `:view` key. The correct key is now `:controller`:

```rb
bindings[:controller].current_user # returns current User object
```

Answer (score 0):

And if you not have a attribute to store this id and just need id to validate another operation, you can create a attribute to it:

```
config.model Model do
   edit do
     field :updater_id, :hidden do
     visible true
     def value
       bindings[:view]._current_user.id
     end
    end
   end
end
```

MODEL:

```
class TaxPlan < ApplicationRecord
  attr_accessor :updater_id
  
  validate :validate_updater_id

  def validate_updater_id
    yor code validation here
  end
end
```