# Create User Account Settings Page in Ruby on Rails with devise

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, devise

I am new to Ruby on Rails and I have created a project that contains a User table (generated by devise) and a AccountSetting table that contains user specific account settings (this table has a foreign key that relates to the id in the User table thus each User has zero or one AccountSettings). I have my seed data working fine, and I can seed the database with users that have user specific account settings. The User table is related to the AccountSetting table with a "has_one :accountsetting" and the AccountSettings table "belongs_to :user". This all works and makes sense. However, I have a method called "show_user_setting" in my UserSettings controller, and I do not know how to ONLY SHOW the account settings for that specific authenticated user.

So, how can I only display the user setting for the currently logged in user? Again, I am using devise.
My general idea of how to do this would be something like this. However I know this is incorrect, but for the purpose of an explanation, here it is.

```
def show_user_setting
     @setting = AccountSetting.find(current_user)
end
```

My idea is that the @setting will contain the setting for the currently logged in user. Thanks in advance!

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Have you tried

```
def show_user_setting
   @setting = AccountSetting.find_by(user_id: current_user.id)
end
```

The way `.find()` works is it searches the model for the id passed. So, the way you currently have it is your going to try to search for the id of the model, when you want to find the foreign key. So use `Model.find_by(column_name: param)`. You'll what to change `user_id:` to the column name of what you're storing the foreign key in, I'm just assuming it's something similar to that.

Comment: This worked! Thanks! One more thing. If i have a similar model where the User table has_many :someothermodel can I still use this same .find(user_id: current_user.id) to get the entire list? Or will this only return one value to @setting?

Comment: @CannonMoyer if it's a `has_many` relationship you can access it like you would an attribute on the model. So, say you have a `User` model. And that user `has_many` dogs (`Dog`). And you were on the show page for instance of that user, and had an instance variable @user. On the page you could then use `@user.dogs`. More practically: `@user.dogs.each do |dog|`. Same in a controller. You could set a dogs instance variable like so `@dogs = User.find(params[:id]).dogs`. [More here](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/association_basics.html#the-has-and-belongs-to-many-association).

Answer (score 3):

You should do this:

```
#app/models/account_setting.rb
class AccountSetting < ActiveRecord::Base
   belongs_to :user
end

#app/models/user.rb
class User < ActiveRecord::Base
   has_one :account_setting
end
```

This will allow you to call the following:

```
@setting = current_user.account_setting
```

---

**Our Setup**

For what it's worth, we do something similar:

```
#app/models/user.rb
class User < ActiveRecord::Base
   before_create :build_profile #-> builds a blank profile on user create
   has_one :profile
end

#app/models/profile.rb
class Profile < ActiveRecord::Base
   belongs_to :user
end
```

This allows us to put all sorts of different options inside the `profile` model (we have `homepage` etc):

[image]

The important thing to note here is that the above allows you to [*delegate*](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/Module.html#method-i-delegate) various methods to the `profile` model, allowing you to call the following:

```
current_user.profile_name
current_user.profile_signin_redirect?
current_user.profile_avatar
```

etc

Answer (score -1):

I'm guessing the show_user_setting function is part of a controller, if it is on a model then read this: [accessing devise current_user within model](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15680541/accessing-devise-current-user-within-model)

to set the @setting variable you should be able to do this

```
 @setting = AccountSetting.find(user_id: current_user.id)
```

or

```
@setting = AccountSetting.find(user: current_user)
```